# Sylius dependencies update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius, pugxmultiuserbundle

I want to add the PUGXMultiUserBundle to my local working copy of Sylius (Windows7).

I add "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev", "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "3.0.*@dev" to composer.json and run:

composer update pugx/multi-user-bundle

All I get is a fatal error: Allowed memory exhausted...

Composer is self-updated to last version and php.ini memory limit now reaches 5G.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WAMP, which has 2 php.ini: one for apache and one for php.

Using the WAMP tray you open the php.ini for WAMP. I had upgraded that memory_limit.

After upgrading memory_limit to 1G in php.ini for wamp, located at:

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini

it worked smoothly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please add this to the question rather than as an answer.

Comment: Well, in fact this is the answer to the memory exhausted error: increase it in the correct php.ini